# No Route Matches error for defined route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

I'm having an issue with Rails, I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"publish", :controller=>"businesses"}
```

The offending code:

```
<div id="searchDatesDiv" style="margin: 0 auto;">
  <%= form_tag(publish_business_path, :method => :post) do %>
    <%= submit_tag("Publish") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :businesses do
  member do
    post 'publish'
  end
end
```

rake routes:

```
    registration     GET    /registrations/:id(.:format)         registrations#show
    publish_business POST   /businesses/:id/publish(.:format)    businesses#publish
          businesses GET    /businesses(.:format)                businesses#index
                     POST   /businesses(.:format)                businesses#create
```

I can see the path defined in rake routes. Why am I getting this error? The form is also a POST method. Any help would be great! I've tried looking at similar questions on SO but haven't found one that works in my case :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your business publish path requires an id parameter that you are not giving it. Pass the business object to the path helper thusly:

```
<%= form_tag(publish_business_path(@business), :method => :post) do %>
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! Can't believe I missed something so simple.

Comment: Its easy to miss. That errors doesn't immediately lead you to realize that a parameter is *missing*.